# How to install and wire up a 30 amp breaker box acceptable to plug my RV in

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm trying to put my RV into the breaker box I've got a 30 amp breaker double pole I've got10/2 wire, do I use a single pole or double pole 30 amp breaker hand my RV plug is a 4 prong plug how do I make this work

Comment: Are you saying your RV has a NEMA 14-30? (think "plugs into the dryer outlet in a brand new house")

Comment: The typical 30A plug on an RV is a special TT-30 (TT=Travel Trailer). Since he said it has a 4 pronged plug, I bet his RV takes 50A service and plugs into a 14-50R.

Comment: Is this a modestly sized RV or is it one of those huge greyhound bus sized things with the pop-outs that tows an SUV and costs well into 6 digits?

Answer (score 1):

RV's typically take 120VAC with an oddball 30 amp receptacle: [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-30-Amp-Temporary-RV-Power-Outlet-U013P/202307113).

[image]
*Note the center hole is not a terminal.*

It will work fine with your 10/2 wire, but your breaker is 2-pole unnecessarily - a single-pole breaker would do.  (Though, a single pole 30A breaker is kind of an orphan, hardly used for anything - the 2-pole breaker is commonly used for several purposes.)

Neutral goes to your neutral bus, ground goes to your ground bus.  Hot goes to **one side** of the 2-pole breaker, the other side is unused.

---

If you wanted to use a NEMA 14-30 connection, you bought the right breaker but the wrong wire.  But [it would surprise me](http://www.nelageo.net/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=604&id=14863&Itemid=54) if you wanted that since 240V/30A is not common with RVs, usually it's 50A if it's 240V.

Comment: Since he said his RV has a 4 pronged plug, I suspect that it has a 50A cord, which would typically plug into a 4 prong 14-50R.

Comment: Then he has the wrong *everything*.  Which would surprise me.  People usually don't go off the rails that bad.  Also, call it stereotyping but I assume anyone who can afford one of the monster RVs just picks up the phone and *has someone* do his electric.

Comment: Wouldn't be that surprising, 30A service is very common among RV's (many parks only provide 30A service), and once the 50A label fades off the side of the RV, it's not always obvious whether the RV is configured for 30A or 50A service. He's probably got a TT-30 to 14-50R adapter cable that he uses when he can't find 50A service.